# unable upload cookbook from windows workstation

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

I have following configurations performed on my machine

1. For workstation

   - Installed chefdk 0.17, created a cookbook, installed berks
2. For chef server

   - Installed chefserver v12.8,Configured it,created user as well as org

While I tried to upload a cookbook from my workstation using knife command, following is the error,

```
PS C:\Users\e-abhayag\chef-starter\chef-repo\cookbooks> knife cookbook upload workstation
Uploading workstation  [0.2.0]
ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host: evalcheflin01 - hostname "evalcheflin01" does not match the server cer
tificate
ERROR: SSL Error connecting to https://evalcheflin01/bookshelf/organization-81ebc4e1ee82fe97c314c2a66304fede/checksum-44
cf8d56cdec7fd795e8c59c11c213e6?AWSAccessKeyId=5f9d83d3b14308ceac7c43df85ac0b43e2cf1cdf&Expires=1472629367&Signature=8FzL
LiBNfTp09TPeQvqtA0TSyzc%3D, retry 1/5
```

Whereas I have fetched the ssl certificate and also checked

```
PS C:\Users\e-abhayag\chef-starter\chef-repo> knife ssl check
Connecting to host EVALCHEFLIN01:443
Successfully verified certificates from `EVALCHEFLIN01'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is visible in what you quoted:

```
evalcheflin01 - hostname "evalcheflin01" does not match the server certificate
```

This is unrelated to if the cert is trusted or not, the cert both has to match the requested hostname and then be trusted. You can use `openssl s_client -connect evalcheflin01:443 -debug` to see what CN is being presented by the server. If you are using the internally generated, self-signed certificate, this will be the FQDN of the server, not the base hostname.

Comment: Well I ran the command on chef server and CN presented is`CN =EVALCHEFLIN01`.
Note:- On my chef server fqdn and hostname are same .
I'm seriously quite confused here , is it I need to create a self assigned cert on chef server , well if that's the case how come workstation fetched the certificate from chef server?

Comment: In chef server I have copied the `/var/opscode/chef-manage/EVALCHEFLIN01.crt into /usr/share/ca-certificates` and updated ca-certificates.
But still got the same error.
Finally , I added `ssl_verify_mode    :verify_none` in knife.rb file from workstation and then it worked perfectly fine.
So it seems like it has ignored the trusted communication between chef server and workstation.
For now it's working for me, but still keen to know how can I resolve this error.

Comment: Again, the error you are getting has nothing to do with if the certificate is trusted or not. The problem is that the cert doesn't match the server. You need ti dive in to normal TLS debugging, this has nothing specifically to do with Chef.